# How to prevent the sides of inline list element being cut off in HTML?

Tags: html, css, list, inline

I have an issue with inline list elements.

The issue is that when I limit the width of my menu, which contains inline list elements, to put it onto multiple lines (for mobile devices) the right-side of elements is being cut off.

Here's a JSFiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/vk2bK/7/

The menu in the orange with:

```
width: 210px;
background-color: #ffc20e;
```

In this JSFiddle the right-side of the 2nd list element is cut off. There's lots of space beside it in the div with the class 'menu', so it's not because of that. I assume it's because of some inline list property I'm unaware of.

How do I prevent the right-sides of inline list elements being cut off when the list expands onto a second line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple CSS fix should do it.

You need to modify the li elements so they are inline block with a defined width:

```
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vk2bK/21/

---

EDIT

I played around with it, see if this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/vk2bK/22/

Comment: GENIUS!! Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a solution : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ic0o09988/NBtWa/)

```
    .menu a {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu a {
    width:80px;
    background-color: #7dc242;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

i removed the lists and made all elements inline-block u can edit their width and height if u need to.